# How to create an object with List[List[Int]] and omit its type

Tags: scala

This code will create a List of List's using

```
val matrix = Matrix(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4)))

class Matrix(matrixParameters: List[List[Int]])

object Matrix {
  def apply(matrixParameters: List[List[Int]]) {
    new Matrix(matrixParameters)
  }
}
```

But would like to omit the use of `List[List[Int]]` and just use something like :

```
 val matrix = Matrix(1,2; 3,4)
```

Can this be achieved in Scala ?

Closest I've got is to create the list of lists from a String using this not very elegant code :

```
val matrixFromString = MatrixFromString("1,2; 3,4")
object MatrixFromString {
  def apply(matrixParameters: String) {
    val l1 = matrixParameters.split(";")(0).split(",").map { x => Integer.valueOf(x).toInt }.toList;
    val l2 = matrixParameters.split(";")(1).split(",").map { x => Integer.valueOf(x).toInt }.toList;

    new Matrix(List(l1, l2))
  }
}
```

Comment: I know it may not resolve your issue, but I highly recommend the [Scala NLP Breeze Linear Algebra](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) library. At the very least, their `DenseMatrix` constructor does exactly what you are asking, you may be able to pull that bit of their code out.

Comment: @evan058 thanks but I have tried breeze library and found it very slow to compile the most basic of linear algebra operations , albeit this is in comparison with matlab

Comment: Compile or run? At best it will run ops like matrix multiplication as fast as Matlab (you will need to setup a BLAS and LAPACK implementation)

Comment: @evan058 compile. BLAS and LAPACK , is this a native linear algebra implementation accessed via JNI ?

Comment: BLAS and LAPACK are implementation standards for low level linear algebra operations often  written in C and Fortrsn. I know the `netlib` library is used for Java access. I am pretty sure NumPy, Matlab, and R all use BLAS and LAPACK implementations for speed.

Comment: Also the first time you compile with Breeze it will be downloading and building a bunch of stuff, it should be faster after a few compiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but with very modest changes...

```
class Matrix(matrixParameters: List[List[Int]])

object Matrix {
  def apply( rows : Seq[Int]* ) = new Matrix( rows.map( _.toList ).toList )
}
```

Now you can write

```
val matrix = Matrix( 
  1 :: 2 :: Nil,
  3 :: 4 :: Nil
)
```

You can define, the package object for the package you are working with, a type alias

```
type Row = Seq[Int]
val  Row = Seq
```

Then

```
val matrix = Matrix( 
  Row(1, 2),
  Row(3, 4)
)
```